# Screen / monitor splitter / dual monitor on a laptop with only Type-c

Tags: graphics-cards, monitors, splitters

I have an HP-envy that is very minimalist ports-wise.
Basically it has two USB3 and a type-c ( and an SD-card slot ) - but the question is more general and not only specific to this machine.

What are the hardware options ( not specific but more categories of hardware ) that will allow me to use **two external** monitors that extend each other on a machine that only has one type-C port?

I found some splitters, some external USB graphic cards, but all the solutions I found are a bit clumsy or will not allow two external monitors ( but only one )

I can afford to ignore the laptop own monitor - or if allowing to have it also working reaching 3 Monitors ..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this [USB C to Dual HDMI Adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0815YD7RX?pf_rd_r=53QAFXGZS7JQQWPKNGA7&pf_rd_p=e632fea2-678f-4848-9a97-bcecda59cb4e&th=1) should allow you to use 2 additional screens although this is dependant on your laptop.

> I found some splitters, some external USB graphic cards, but all the solutions I found are a bit clumsy or will not allow two external monitors ( but only one )

I have had similar issues using external USB Graphics cards / Hubs such as this [USB docking station](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plugable-Universal-Docking-Station-Ethernet-Black/dp/B00GQ3685Q/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=anker%20usb%20dock%20display&qid=1595429468&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExTjFGUVRDQTM4VkVUJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjIzODE2MVVHNFFZMUo2N0pQTSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNDUzNjQzTFFOUzRGVDFKRjNaJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==). A lot of these use [displaylink](https://www.displaylink.com/small-office/how) to enable the use of an external display. The problem with displaylink is that it has an extra overhead over a native display connection, such as HDMI, to enable extra screens to be connected over lower bandwidth, non-native, connections, such as USB 2.0 and therefore can be not as smooth or 'clumsy' as you described.